# Python List of users

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

I want to learn how to create an API, so I want to create an empty dictionary where the first key is Names. Names will be a dictionary with the names of the users the system will have.

How do I actually do it with python?

People = [{}]

I want it to be something like:

```
People = [Names:["name1", "name2"... "nameN"]]
```

later on, I want to add more information like for example:

```
People[Names:[], Age:["1","2"]..]
```

I want at some stage be able to relate any name to any other key correctly.
name1 has age 1 and next key...

How do I declare this dictionary?

Comment: Why don't you just use the name of a person as the key and a dict with the other data as the value?

Comment: I just didnt think of that. Thank you for helping me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to do:

```
person = {
          "name":
                {
                    "title":"Herr","first":"foo","last":"bar"
                },
          "email":"bar@foo.de",
          "password":"123",
          "property":"value"
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a pandas DataFrame is useful in this case. As the following example illustrates, it allows you to easily add both people and variables.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names':['name1', 'name2'], 'Age':[1, 2]})

# adding a column: Gender
df['Gender'] = ['male', 'female']

# adding a row for name3, a three-year-old male
third_person = {'Names':'name3', 'Age':3, 'Gender':'male'}
df = df.append(third_person, ignore_index=True)
```